# Customizable Forecast: Override Forecast Commit & Best Case

Tags: apex, forecast, data-model

In Customizable Forecast users can override the commit & best values for users with lower role according to the role hierarchy.

I'm trying to understand if the overrides values are stored somewhere (probably yes), and if we can access and modify those values with apex code?

Attach picture with the relevant standard SF screen. 
Where does SF store the value 500 that was added?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer [Customizable Forecasting Object Data model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_forecasting.htm)

[image: Customizable Forecasting Objects]

[OpportunityOverride](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityoverride.htm)

> Represents a forecast override of an Opportunity. This read-only object is specific to customizable forecasting. It has a parent-child relationship with LineitemOverride.

[LineitemOverride](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lineitemoverride.htm)

> A forecast override of a line item on an Opportunity. This read-only object for customizable forecasting has a child-parent relationship with OpportunityOverride.

Those are related to Customizable Forecast fields

[image: Customizable Forecast fields]

[RevenueForecast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_revenueforecast.htm)

> Represents a revenue-based forecast.

**Comments from @Liron C**

> Actually, the value as the manager override per user in the screen is stored in: **ManagerCommitOverride**. Unfortunately this field is read only and cannot be update with apex

Comment: Thanks. However you can see note in the links you added: "This information only applies to Collaborative Forecasts." While we are using Customizable Forecast. Indeed, I try to query this object, and got error that "sObject type 'ForecastingAdjustment' is not supported.". Does SF have any coresponding sobject for Customizable Forecast?

Comment: @LironC, refer my updated answer, I was wrong earlier. This will work

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the value as the manager override per user in the screen is stored in: RevenueForecast.ManagerCommitOverride. Unfortunately this field is read only and cannot be update with apex.